# Logcat output of galaxy s3 doesn't show activity name

Tags: android, logcat

I'm trying to analyse the logs generated from galaxy s3 but it does n't show the name of activity. It shows the intent in following format:

```
START {**intent.toShortString**} from pid 14354
```

Is there any way to get the conventional type of logcat ouput from galaxy s3. i.e.:

```
 START {**cmp=com.test/.Activity**} from pid 641
```

Comment: Please give your Android versions, it matters more than hardware in this case.

Comment: update your eclipse versions and android plugins. It may be solve the problem.